# What's wrong with this Java syntax?

Tags: java, if-statement

```
height[left] < height[right]? left++ : right--;
```

I want to user the above syntax to replace if/else statement. I think it follows (condition)? doX(): doY() but there's somthing wrong.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you show us this ternary expression in the context of your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ternary operator is an **expression**, not a **statement**. You're not assigning the result of the expression to anything, so the compiler doesn't like it.

If you mean this as a statement, use `if` instead of the ternary operator:

```
if (height[left] < height[right]) {
    left++;
} else {
    right--;
}
```

Comment: @ĐăngKhoaHuỳnh Why? You don't know if the result should be the return value of a method or not, the question doesn't indicate that.

Comment: Oh sorry, I think you are using `if` for ternary operator as the same case.

Answer (score 0):

It is wrong because the operation is not assigning a value to anything...

ternary operations have a return

## Example:

```
int a=0;
int b=0;
int left=0;
int right=0;
int pos=0;
pos = a < b? left++ : right--;
```

as you see the variable pos get assigned as result of the ternary operation

in your case you are missing the variable were left++ or right-- is going to be assigned:

```
??? = height[left] < height[right]? left++ : right--;
```